# Access 2007 VBA: use Form.Filter in query parameters

Tags: forms, ms-access, filter, vba

I'd like to create and open a select query based on the user's current form filters. I can do this in VBA by parsing the form's Me.Filter string, extracting the bits I need and building a WHERE statement. However, putting in the all the required logic, punctuation and syntax is going to be a pain.

So my question, before I do all that is: is there any existing function to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a pain, if you use the form's recordsource as base of the select query.

Comment: Thanks, but source isn't the problem and I can't see any method to get an SQL WHERE string from the recordsource property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe my comment was a little cryptic.

Let's say the recordsource of your form is `myQuery`.

The form is filtered, Me.Filter = `myQuery.field1 LIKE 'asdf*' AND myQuery.field2 = 42`

So your select query is e.g.

```sql
SELECT field1, field3 
FROM myQuery
WHERE myQuery.field1 LIKE 'asdf*' AND myQuery.field2 = 42
```

or

```vb
myQuerydef.SQL = "SELECT field1, field3 FROM " & Me.Recordsource & _
    " WHERE " & Me.Filter
```

So I don't quite see where the problem is.

The answer to your question is no, there is no function - but you shouldn't need anything besides `Me.Filter`.

**Edit** as suggested by HansUp:

If the RecordSource of your form currently isn't a single query, but a SELECT statement, create a named query from that SELECT statement, and use that query as RecordSource.

Comment: True, but then for this use case the solution *is* to have a single query as RecordSource - if it currently isn't, then create a named query from the current RecordSource. @HansUp

Comment: Didn't realize you could use Me.Filter directly as the WHERE ( myQuerydef.SQL = "SELECT field1, field3 FROM " & Me.Recordsource &  " WHERE " & Me.Filter). Thanks, new one for the toolkit.